# PrimeFaces: conditional update on validation

Tags: ajax, validation, jsf, primefaces

Is it possible to conditionally update JSF components only when validation succeeds?

I would like to be able to do something like

```
<p:commandLink process="@form" listener="#{foo}" 
  update="something somethingElse">
```

where "something" only gets updated if validation is successful.

Is there any way that can be done or is that just not supported in JSF?

I've been able to rig up kind of a hack with hidden commandLinks but not entirely satisfied:

```
<p:commandLink process="@form" listener="#{foo}" 
  update="somethingElse" oncomplete="if (!args.validationFailed) $("#link").click();">
<p:commandLink style="display:none" id="link"
  update="something">
```

Comment: Why don't you use h:message(s) for this?

Comment: I'm trying to do the opposite: update something only when validation is successful.

Comment: oncomplete="if (!args.validationFailed) $("#link").click(); this code is not working for me... :( my conditional update is not working...

Comment: And I am not able to get h:messages approach.. Kindly elaborate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<h:message>` (or PrimeFaces' counterpart `<p:message>`) is intented for this. Or, in your case maybe better, the `<h:messages>` (or `<p:messages>`).

```
public void submit() {
    // ...

    if (fail) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, 
            new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Fail", null));
    }
}
```

with

```
<h:messages id="messages" />
<p:commandLink process="@form" action="#{bean.submit}" update="messages something" />
```

Note that you're as well supposed to use a normal `Validator` implementation to perform the validation. If it throws a `ValidatorException`, then the action won't be invoked anyway. Doing validation inside action method is a smell.

Comment: I'm trying to do the opposite: update something only when validation is successful.

Comment: Do the same, but then use `SEVERITY_INFO` with a "Success" message instead. The action method won't be invoked anyway when the validation has failed. An alternative is to let the action method set some property and use `rendered="#{not empty bean.someProperty}"`.

Comment: Another variation on @BalusC last suggestion: 

`FacesCopntext.getPartialViewContext().getRenderIds().add("updateComponentId")` in the action listener.  Only executed if validation succeeds.

Comment: Can you please elaborate with the code.. I am not able to understand the how to update conditionally basically when validation fail I want to update 2 components but If validation got success I want to update 3 component... 2 previous and one extra.. Kindly help\

Comment: I don't think the `message` suggestion necessarily answers the question asked.  Suppose he wants to update something OTHER than a `message`?

I've not tried this myself, but another approach that might work is to use `remotecommand`.

    <p:remoteCommand id='good' update='goodUpdates'/>
    <p:remoteCommand id='bad' update='badUpdate'/>
    <p:commandButton onSuccess='if (your-test) good() else bad()'/>

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the `message` suggestion necessarily answers the question asked.  Suppose he wants to update something OTHER than a `message`?

I've not tried this myself, but another approach that might work is to use `remotecommand`.

```
<p:remoteCommand id='good' update='goodUpdates'/>  
<p:remoteCommand id='bad' update='badUpdate'/>  
<p:commandButton oncomplete='if (your-test) good() else bad()'/>
```

Note, this would necessitate another round-trip to the server and thus performance is a consideration.

Comment: Correct.  I have corrected the example ("oncomplete")

Comment: Thanks a lot :) but id not works for me, I added attribute name <p:remoteCommand id='good' name="good" update='goodUpdates'/>.... Now working fine...