# JSF: Update conditionally on Success or failure of validations

Tags: validation, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, java-ee-6

In my JSF application I am trying to put some conditions in my Command button update attribute  so that on validation failure/Success I can control the components to update.

With reference to [PrimeFaces: conditional update on validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9638290/primefaces-conditional-update-on-validation) I tried to to use

```
<p:commandLink process="@form" listener="#{foo}" 
  update="somethingElse" oncomplete="if (!args.validationFailed) $("#link").click();">
<p:commandLink style="display:none" id="link"
  update="something">
```

But I don't know why this approach is not working for me.. click event of that particular component is not working for me.. I tried to execute the accepted answer for the same question , but I could not understand how that solve the purpose...

My purpose is to update conditionally depending on the result of the validation success or failure... Support I have 3 components X Y Z.. I am trying to do something like this..

```
<p:commandLink process="@form" listener="#{foo}" 
      update="if(Validation fail)updateSomething[e.g X and Y] **else** update somethingelse[e.g X  Y and Z]">
```

To be more precise if the validations fails then I want to update X and Y component only if validations succeed than I want to update X Y & Z components..

Kindly help me out.. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The first problem is that the EL syntax which you've there is invalid. You're closing the attribute value too soon by using `"` instead of `'` in the JavaScript code. Either escape nested quotes with `\"` or just use `'` instead.

```
<p:commandLink process="@form" listener="#{foo}" update="somethingElse" 
    oncomplete="if (!args.validationFailed) $('#link').click();">
```

The second possible problem is that the client ID of the `<p:commandLink id="link">` is not `"link"` at all. It's by default prepended with the ID of the parent `<h:form>` component. The client ID is the JSF-generated HTML element ID. Open the page in webbrowser, rightclick and *View Source* to see it yourself. It'll look something like `id="formId:link"`. You need to use exactly that ID in the jQuery selector.

```
<p:commandLink process="@form" listener="#{foo}" update="somethingElse" 
    oncomplete="if (!args.validationFailed) $('#formId\\:link').click();">
```

#### See also:

- [How to select JSF components using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927716/how-to-select-primefaces-ui-or-jsf-components-using-jquery)

---

An alternative is to perform the concrete job in the method behind `listener="#{foo}"` instead.

```
if (!facesContext.isValidationFailed()) {
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("somethingElse");
}
```

Comment: I will prefer the second approach rather than jquery approach... yes I can use above code to update from java code but than How I will stop update than I have specified on the .xhtml.. Is there are way to apply some condition on xhtml side..??

Comment: @balausC and also can you explain the approach using <h:messages> that you have explained in above mentioned link in the question

Comment: If the sole purpose is displaying faces messages, just use the same approach as in the answer in your link. Replace `oncomplete="if (!args.validationFailed) $('#link').click();"` by `update="messages"`.

Comment: My edit to this answer was rejected - don't exactly know why though - however in code example, the code can not compile, because the method isn't called `validationFailed()`, but `isValidationFailed()`. `validationFailed()` returns `void` and not a `boolean`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the marked answer but it didn't solve my issue since args does not contain parameter called "validationFailed" however I found the way of adding this parameter from the controller.

```
 import org.primefaces.context.RequestContext;

 RequestContext requestContext = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
 requestContext.addCallbackParam("validationError", true);
 JSFUtils.displayErrorMessage("My message is here!");
```

& in the xhtml I added the following command link

```
 <p:commandLink ajax="true" action="#{myController.myMethod}"
 oncomplete="if(args.validationError) alert('Error!');"/>
```

Comment: Perhaps you're using a jurassic version of PrimeFaces? IIRC it was in 3.x already.

Comment: In fact I am using primefaces 4.0 but still I am not able to use the solution without adding the parameter myself using the primefaces RequestContext.