# Conditional update in Primefaces/jsf

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

First of all, so that there are no misunderstandings, while this is the same question as [PrimeFaces: conditional update on validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9638290/primefaces-conditional-update-on-validation) I am asking it again, because the **answer to that question is not acceptable to me**, because while it may have given the original poster a workaround for what they were asking, it doesn't really answer the question, and this workaround doesn't work for me.

So, here's my question: how do I conditionally update a primefaces component based on the results of the submition?

I have a component that must not, under any circumstances be updated UNLESS the validation is successful and backend code was executed successfully. (i.e. if the validation succeeds but there was an SQL exception on the back end, the component still shouldn't be updated).

Why can't I always update it? If the logic doesn't succeed it'll be updated to the same thing it was before the submit button was clicked. **Because I can't.** It's the captcha component. If you update it via ajax, it disappears, end of story. There was a ticket opened at Primefaces and they closed it as won't fix, because flash compoents aren't supposed to be updated w/ ajax.

So when I submit the form, unless the logic succeeds I need to leave the captcha alone. IF the logic succeeds, I need to make sure the captcha disappears off screen. What's the easiest, cleanest way to do it?

Excuse me if this is a n00b question. I'm really new to Primefaces and JSF.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("clientId")
```

Helps for conditional updates.

For recaptcha try

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("Recaptcha.destroy()");
```

Comment: As of Primefaces 7 `RequestContext.getCurrentInstance()` is not available and `PrimeFaces.current().ajax()` should be used instead.

Answer (score 13):

You can use a combination of JavaScript and RemoteCommand:

```
<p:commandLink action="#{bean.doIt()}" process="@form" update="@none" oncomplete="if(!args.validationFailed){updateMyImportantUI();}" />

<p:remoteCommand name="updateMyImportantUI" process="@this" update=":myImportantID" />
```

Comment: Did not think to put the condition in the oncomplete="" instead of the remoteCommand. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a variable at the backing bean and use it on the xhtml part.
Like this:

```
update="#{backingMB.updateString}"
```

So, after the condition you can put the value for `updateString`, but when you define it on the `backingMB`, you need to put it as:

```
String updateString=""; // this will be id of the component to be updated
```

This way you won't get a [NullPointerException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html).

Comment: I am trying this out and... How do I "update" the `updateString` on form submit (that is, when OK button is selected)? What I do is check for errors, and if all OK then dialog is closed and parent is updated, and if errors then dialog is not closed and dialog message part should be updated. However, on OK my form is submitted and updateString is not updated.